# Unable to read and write data to the database after updating room database dependency version

Tags: android, android-room, roomdb

After updating the dependency version of RoomDB, I am unable to read and write data to the database.

Before

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.5'
```

After

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.5.2'
```

This error occurs from version `2.3.0-alpha03` and onwards. There is no errors displayed in logcat so I don't know what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to include all the Room annotated classes (those with `@Entity`, `@Dao`, `@Database`, `@Embedded` and `@Relation`). Perhaps add logging to code to track to see what does and doesn't run. Have you checked the build log?

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
var id: Int? = null
```

to

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
var id: Int = 0
```

fixed my issue

Since 2.3.0, the RoomDb library is written in the Kotlin, which is probably the reason.